# Execute my groovy script with ant or maven

Tags: java, maven-2, ant, groovy

I have the following:

- 1 java class
- 1 bat file (starts the groovy script)
- 1 groovy file

All in the same folder.

Now I want to use Maven or Ant to run the groovy file but I can't get it to work. Is there someone who can show me how to write this pom.xml or build.xml? I don't want to use the bat file anymore.

Answer (score 17):

With Maven, use the gmaven plugin. From [its documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code):

> #### [Execute a Local Groovy Script](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code#ExecutingGroovyCode-ExecuteaLocalGroovyScript)
>
> ```
> <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
>     <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>1.3</version>
>     <executions>
>         <execution>
>             <phase>generate-resources</phase>
>             <goals>
>                 <goal>execute</goal>
>             </goals>
>             <configuration>
>                 <source>${pom.basedir}/src/main/script/myscript.groovy</source>
>             </configuration>
>         </execution>
>     </executions>
> </plugin>
> ```

And trigger the specified phase.

Or, if you don't want to bind the plugin to a particular phase, you could configure it like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>
           println "Hi"
        </source>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And call

```
mvn groovy:execute
```

Comment: @Pascal: You stole my answer :-) (+1)

Comment: @seanizer Yeah, I confess. But I gave you 15mn :)

Comment: well I get as close that I have been before. I have written this now

Comment: @Mikael Sorry, I didn't get you. Any particular problem pending?

Comment: @Pascal BTW the artifactId has changed. current versions can be found here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.gmaven/gmaven-plugin (the docs are outdated)

Answer (score 3):

There is a [groovy plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/The+groovy+Ant+Task) for ANT that can invoke groovy scripts

```
<groovy src="helloWorld.groovy"/>
```

I would recommend combining it with [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) which can download the required jars for you, similar to the Maven example given previously.

**build.xml**

```
<project name="demo" default="run" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:resolve/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path"/>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="resolve">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

        <groovy src="helloWorld.groovy"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

**ivy.xml**

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.myorg" module="demo"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.codehaus.groovy" name="groovy-all" rev="1.7.4" conf="default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via Ant as shown [with a full example here](http://www.developer.com/lang/article.php/10924_3657751_3/What-Groovy-Can-Do-For-You.htm). See the **Compiling and running with Ant** section.

You'll have to [download ant](http://ant.apache.org/), make sure the ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME variables are set, and put the ANT_HOME/bin in your PATH.

Once you have the build.xml in place, you can call `ant` at the command line which will run the build.xml

More details on the [Groovy ant task here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/The+groovy+Ant+Task)