# Groovy scripts in Ant: Use script task or groovy task?

Tags: ant, groovy

If you want to run a Groovy script in Ant, you can either use the [script task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) like this: ..

```
<script language="groovy">
//foo
</script>
```

..or the [groovy task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) like that:

```
<groovy>
//foo
</groovy>
```

Both ways require the Groovy libraries to be downloaded. I found a promising looking Ant config that does this automatically in this answer: [Execute my groovy script with ant or maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914690/execute-my-groovy-script-with-ant-or-maven/3919520#3919520)

Now for my **question**:

Which of the two Ant tasks is meant to be used for running Groovy scripts? `script` or `groovy`?

Also, what is the purpose of the "additional" groovy task, if there's a script task included in Ant that supports groovy?

Also I'd like to quote from a blog post I found here: http://jbetancourt.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/run-groovy-from-ants-script-task.html

> Of course, why would you use the 'script' task when the 'groovy' task is available? You wouldn't.

Does anyone agree with the author of this post? If so - could you explain the idea behind it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

+1 for Josef's statement about the groovy task (btw. his blogs http://josefbetancourt.wordpress.com/ and http://octodecillion.com/ are worth reading) 
Using groovy a lot for several purposes, in ant i exclusively use the groovy task because of his slick syntax providing simple access to ant api, consider this example :

```
<project>
  <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>

  <property name="foo" value="bar"/>

  <script language="groovy">
   project.setProperty 'foo', 'baz'
   echo = project.createTask 'echo'
   echo.setMessage 'Howdie :-)'
   echo.execute()
  </script>

  <echo>1. $${foo} => ${foo}</echo>

  <groovy>
    properties.'foo' = 'baaz'
    ant.echo 'Howdie :-)'
  </groovy>

  <echo>2. $${foo} => ${foo}</echo>

</project>
```

Which do you prefer ? OK, normally instead of echo. ... you would use print or println,
 it's just for demonstrating the access to ant api.

Comment: But can't you also run scripts from a file using the script task and defining the file in the src attribute? Here it says so: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html `src The location of the script as a file, if not inline`.

Comment: of course, you're right, forgot about that because i never use script task :) deleted that part of my answer

Comment: Thanks for the example, I played around with it a bit and decided to use the groovy task! Accessing properties is really much easier that way.